# Why does calculating probabilities intuitively result in differences from Bayesian calculations?

Tags: statistics, bayesian

As an example, say you're asked to solve for the following problem:

> You have three bags, labeled A, B, and C. Bag A contains two red marbles and three blue marbles. Bag B contains five red marbles and one blue marble. Bag C contains three red marbles only. Suppose a bag is randomly selected (again, with equal probability), but you do not know which it is. You randomly draw a marble and observe that it is blue. What is the probability that the bag you selected this marble from is A?

I understand that you can calculate P(A|blue) using Baye's Theorem which would ask me to solve for P(blue|A) * P(A) / P(blue) which comes out to be 0.78. However, if I were to be asked this question outside the context of a class on bayesian statistics, I would think that the probability would be 0.75 or 3/4 since there are 4 blue marbles between the three bags. Since there is an equal chance of drawing from either bag, couldn't we disregard the probability of drawing from a given bag and focus on the distribution of blue marbles between bags? What is the error in my thinking here?

Comment: I can give you an example to illustrate what kind of issues arise with your reasoning: Suppose bag A has $1$ red marble and $100$ blue marbles; suppose bag B has $1000000000$ red marbles and $9900$ blue marbles, is it reasonable to say that the probability of the marble being from A is $100/10000$?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose I pick a random marble from all the marbles, *with each marble equally likely*, and I show you that it's blue. In that case, your reasoning would make sense: you should figure that there's a 3/4 chance that my marble came from bag A.

However, in the scenario you described, the marbles are *not* equally likely to be chosen, because the bags have different numbers of marbles. Each blue marble in bag A has a higher probability of being chosen than the one blue marble in bag B has, because bag B has 6 marbles total while bag A only has 5 marbles. That's why the correct answer is a little bigger than 3/4.

Comment: Thank you. This puts into words what I felt like the reason likely was, but for some reason, couldn't articulate.